# How to load and enable extensions in a createBrowserContext target

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm using the Chrome DevTools Protocol to create isolated contexts for tests within a single Chrome process. I'd like to load and enable extensions, which works fine in the regular context (with or without incognito),  but not in targets created with `createBrowserContext`. The extensions don't seem to be loaded, or if they are, they don't inherit the "Allow in Incognito" setting from the regular target.

I can understand why new contexts wouldn't inherit anything from the regular context (because you want isolation), but is there then a way to create a new context *with extensions*? Or do I have to run separate processes?